# Excel VBA opens multiple Word applications leading to errors

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to deploy a program in Excel VBA to send mail, copying and pasting text from Word documents.

My program runs but at a certain point it throws errors and I see there are a lot of Word applications open so I have to close them with the Task Manager. I tried to use the `Object.Quit` function to set the object to Nothing.

I think that the random errors of the program have their root in the bad use of my computer memory. I have no idea of how use the memory in the computer because my background has nothing to do with programming.

```
Sub CustomizedMail()

    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim mymail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim generalDirectory As String
    Dim document As String
    Dim ActiveRow As Integer
    Dim mailType As String

    Break = Chr(13) + Chr(10)

    'Selects address of letters to Clients
    generalDirectory = "C:\Users\Rodrigo\OneDrive - InBody Co., Ltd\Ventas Rod\Forecast\Ppts informativas x área\Para enviar\"
    'Selects document to be sent according to ppt type value in worksheet
    ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
    mailType = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Range("O" & ActiveRow).Value

    'Check mailType
    If mailType = "" Then
        MsgBox "Selecciona un tipo de mail"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Opens word document and copies its information
    document = generalDirectory & mailType & ".docx"
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wd.documents.Open(document)
    'wd.Visible = True
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    'Set wd = Nothing

    'Opens Outlook and paste

    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    'CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'New Outlook.Application
    Set mymail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With mymail
        On Error GoTo 1
        .To = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Range("N" & ActiveRow)
        If mailType = "Presentación" Then
            .Subject = "Bioimpedanciómetros profesionales InBody"
        Else
            .Subject = "Bioimpedanciómetros para " & mailType
        End If
        '.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
        'editor.Quit
        Set editor = Nothing
        .Display
    End With
    'Append corresponding file
    sourceFile = generalDirectory & "INBODY - " & mailType & ".pdf"
    mymail.Attachments.Add sourceFile

    ActiveCell.Worksheet.Range("T" & ActiveRow).Value = "Yes"
    ActiveCell.Worksheet.Range("V" & ActiveRow).Value = Date
    'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.FullName
    'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path
    Exit Sub
1:          MsgBox "Excel se puso pendejo, intenta de nuevo"
End Sub
```

Comment: In your code , you don't have `wd.Quit` and `Set wd = Nothing` is commented out. Is this intended?

Comment: `Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")` will create a new instance of Word each time it's run. What you should do is to use `On Error Resume Next` before `Set wd  = Word.Application` and create a new instance only if an error occurs (meaning there is no loaded instance of Word). The probable reason why `Wd.Quit` appears to have no effect is because you have so many instances open that one being shut down makes no difference. Much the same applies to your handling of the Outlook application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, .Quit and wd = Nothing are commented because I did experiments to see if they work and as they seems not to function in my code I let them commented. I will try the On Error Resume Next. Do you know why an error could happen? I thought that with computers errors have as main cause code issues, what should I do to avoid this type of errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve a lot of your problems by reusing your objects. Try something like this:

```
Sub SendALotOfMails()
    Dim wd as Object
    Dim outlookApp as Object

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    ' Reusing word and outlook objects
    CustomizedMail wd, outlookApp
End Sub

Sub CustomizedMail(wd As Object, outlookApp as Object)
    ...
End Sub
```

This is obviously only part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks Sam, when I finish to use these objects should I set them to Nothing, use Object.Quit or just do nothing with them? I read yesterday that when an object is not used VBA automatically cleans memory on computer, but when I see my task manager it does not happen for my code haha

Comment: In most cases it is true that VBA cleans memory on its own, but when you start a big complex application like Word or Outlook there are other mechanisms in play. Still, quit is good thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, other think that I noted is that when Incopu text from the word app, sometimes the copy is “nothing” (I saw this when I open the clipboard manager and see an empty space, I think that it has something to do with my errors and for a moment I thought that it could be happen because I close the word app so quickly, in which point do you recommend to close the word application?

Comment: I'm not sure about your situation, so I'll try to give a more generic answer. A typical script like this consists of a setup part, a loop and a closing part. In the setup you will start up applications, prepare lists and such. In the loop you use the provided objects to do all the creation and sending. The closing part shuts down everything in nice way. If you push your system too hard in the looping, it might be a good idea to give it a few moments of catching up before killing it.